# How can I find the new means of each cluster's at K-Means?

Tags: java, algorithm, k-means

I have a list variables for each cluster at my K-means algorithm. How can I find the new **means** of each cluster's?

Comment: This question is a little bit vague.Are you asking how to actually implement the algorithm, or you have it already implemented, and just need clarifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K-means assigns each element to a cluster.  Are those the elements in your lists? If so, then calculate the mean for each of those lists.

Comment: I am wondering about calculating the mean value of a multidimensional points. For ex. a is(2,4,6,5) b is(9,12,1,4) c is(14,2,4,5): so what is the mean point of them?

Comment: Just do the mean of each coordinate independently.

Comment: It's simply the average. So ((2+9+14)/3,(4+12+2)/3,(6+1+4)/3,(5+4+5)/3).